# Getting the joint function. What am i doing wrong?!?

Tags: probability

we have that $f(x_1,x_2)=2(1-x_1)$ if $0≤x_1≤1$, $0≤x_2≤1$.
And we have that $Y_1=x_1x_2$ and $y_2=x_1$
And i have to find the joint distribution of $y_1$, $y_2$:(f($y_1,$$y_2$)) and verify if this a valid distribution.

---

The method that i know is to get the determinant of the hessian matrix and replace the values of $x_1, x_2$.

So this this what i did:
We have that $x_1=y_2$ and $x_2=y_1/y_2$. The determinant is $1/y_2$. 
Then $f(y_1,y_2)$=$1/y_2$*$2(1-y_2)$ for  $0≤y_1≤1$, $0≤y_2≤1$.
but when i integrate from 0 to 1, the integration is not=1.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your bounds.

You have a support of $0\leq x_1\leq 1, 0\leq x_2\leq 1$ and a transformation of $x_1=y_2$ and $x_2=y_1/y_2$

Then by substitution the support becomes $0\leq y_2\leq 1$, $0\leq y_1/y_2\leq 1$, which means ...

$$\int_0^1\int_{0}^{?}\Big(\frac 2{y_2}-2\Big)\operatorname d y_1\operatorname d y_2=1$$